# Postgresql: Double.MinValue is out of range for type double precision

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a postgres function with parameter double precision. Sometimes i want to pass the minimum value of double from server side [Double.MinValue] c# code.
Now i'm facing an issue as below

> -179769313486232000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>   is out of range for type double precision

input to the double precision parameter is Double.MinValue.

Function looks as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_double_value(
    strtidx double precision,
    endidx double precision)
    // other logic goes below
```

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes use the appropriate time https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: Why not pass null instead? Whatever meaning you're attaching to minvalue, attach it to null and handle appropriately

Comment: @CaiusJard Abusing `NULL` this way is usually a bad idea. Queries become complicated, and the histograms don't reflect the reality.

Comment: I don't think we have any way to know what the sentiment of minvalue is and whether or not null makes a good stand in, but this is a parameter to an sp we are discussing not a set of data that may/not be null and have statistics against it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely a rounding error when the `double precision` value is converted to a string.

Pass `'-infinity'` instead. That is a well-defined `double precision` value that probably expresses your intention better.